# How to mock a void function inside a void function?

Tags: java, mockito, testng

I have three classes A,B and BTest. How to verify A.printHulk() when it is called from B.printThor()?

```
public class A
{
    public void printHulk()
    {
        System.out.println("I am Hulk");
    }
}
```

```
public class B
{
    private A a;

    @Inject
    public B(A a)
    {
        this.a=a;
    }
    public void printThor()
    {
        System.out.println("I am Thor");
        a.printHulk();
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

```
public class BTest
{
    @Mock
    private A a;

    private B b;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        b=new B(a);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrintThor()
    {
        b.printThor();
        verify(a,times(1)).printHulk();
    }
}
```

Verifying the a.printHulk() gives an error? Since it is a void function, I can't use when and thenreturn on it. How to verify it being called?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot invoke "MockingVoidFunctions.A.printHulk()" because "this.a" is null

Comment: @Mureinik any help?

Comment: How `a` inside `B` initiated?

Comment: @user7294900 I have made some changes. the output I am getting is I am Thor End. How to deal with calling a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your test like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassBTest {

    @Mock
    private A a;

    @InjectMocks
    private B b;

    @Test
    public void testPrintThor() {
        b.printThor();
        Mockito.verify(a).printHulk();
    }
}
```

Or if want to print I am Hulk, your test would look like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassBTest {

    @Spy
    private ClassA a;

    @InjectMocks
    private ClassB b;

    @Test
    public void testPrintThor() {
        b.printThor();
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(a).printHulk();
    }
}
```

Comment: still I'm not able to print I am Hulk

Comment: I have changed some code , can you please help

Comment: You should not be able to print "I am Hulk". Mockito will not call the real method implementation in this case.

Comment: how to achieve it then?

Comment: Then you should use Spy instead of Mock. I edited my answer.